# Is there a way to use where() with a dynamic list?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing an app using React Native and Firebase. I want to get a number of document from a collection only if theres a field value that match with a value inside a list ( i dont know the content of the list) is there a way to do this? I'll show below what i want to achieve:

```
const list = ['first', 'second', 'third']
    
    firebase.firestore()
    .collection('collection')
    .where(/*where field value is existing inside the list*/)
    .orderBy('creation', 'desc')
    .get()
    .then((res) => {
        const x = res.docs.map((value) => {
            const id = value.id;
            const data = value.data();
            return  { id, ...data}
        })
        resolve(x)
    })
```

So it should finish giving me a list of documents that have inside a field that has a value: 'first', 'second, or 'third'.

Anyone knows how can I do this? I've been stuck on this a few days. Some help would be appreciated.

I'll give some more information if needed.

I tried this but it shows me only the document corresponding to the first element of the list:

```
const list = ['first', 'second', 'third']

firebase.firestore()
    .collection('collection')
    .where('field', '==', ...list)
    .orderBy('creation', 'desc')
    .get()
    .then((res) => {
        const x= res.docs.map((value) => {
            const id = value.id;
            const data = value.data();
            return  { id, ...data}
        })
        resolve(x)
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`in` operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any).

```
firebase.firestore()
  .collection('collection')
  .where('field', 'in', list)
  .orderBy('creation', 'desc')
  .get()
```

However, `list` can only have up to 10 items so if you have more values, you'll need to run the same query with next part of the list.

Comment: I was thinking about the solution, and ill probably use a list of thousands of items, so I don't think it's a great solution for this kind of problem, anything else?

Comment: @SandroTola I've already mentioned what you would have to do in that case and that's the only solution at the moment.

Comment: yeah i get that, but im worried it would be very heavy to process. Anyway if u say theres not other way, thank you.